# Get other component value in a markup extension

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I started using markup extensions a few days ago and i got a dump problem.

I have a markup extension that have `string` property and I wan't to use the value entered by the uer in a `TextBox`, is there an easy way to do that ?

so i have something like that:

```
<TextBox Name="tb"/>

<ListView Name="lv">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={my:CustomExtension Value=(content of the textBox)}}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is not very clear. Post some code and try to show us what are you trying to do

Comment: TextBox's text property is also string. You should give a piece of code to explain your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it right; you wanna Bind a value to a Property of your **MarkupExtension** Class

No you Can't;

You Only Can Bind a DependencyProperty and you Don't have any DependencyProperty;
and you **can't Define a Dependency Property on your MarkupExtension Class** ; because it's not a DependencyObject; so you Can't bind anything to your Custom extension;